# Python, slicing lists?

Tags: python, list, slice

i really need your help with slicing a list.

lets say I've got a list of lists like this:

```
field=[[1, 2, 4, 4], [4, 1, 4, 2], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

and I have to write a function which will return a string that will look like this:

```
42334
44423
21142
14221
```

thus fat i managed to do this:

```
def out(field):
    b=''
    for list in field:
        list1=list[::-1]
        b+=''.join((str(sth) for sth in list1))+'\n'
    return b
```

which returns this:

```
4421
2414
3412
3242
4321
```

Comment: Can you please explain the reason why you need the output you stated? Doesn't seem logical..

Comment: @Heskja: transposition of the matrix, presumably, but it needs a rotation too.

Comment: we are programming this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKF6KNIh_mw
(without graphics tho)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *transpose* your list of rows to a list of columns, as well as reverse the results of the transposition to get a proper rotation.

[`zip(*field)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) transposes the rows to columns, [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) then reverses the results. Combined with a list comprehension you can do this all in one expression:

```
def out(field):
    return '\n'.join([''.join(map(str, c)) for c in reversed(list(zip(*field)))])
```

or spelled out into an explicit loop:

```
def out(field):
    b = []
    for columns in reversed(list(zip(*field))):
        b.append(''.join(map(str, columns)))
    return '\n'.join(b)
```

The `list()` call around the `zip()` call allows us to reverse the iterator result in Python 3; it can be dropped in Python 2.

Demo:

```
>>> field=[[1, 2, 4, 4], [4, 1, 4, 2], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> [''.join(map(str, c)) for c in reversed(list(zip(*field)))]
['42334', '44423', '21142', '14221']
>>> '\n'.join([''.join(map(str, c)) for c in reversed(list(zip(*field)))])
'42334\n44423\n21142\n14221'
>>> print('\n'.join([''.join(map(str, c)) for c in reversed(list(zip(*field)))]))
42334
44423
21142
14221
```

Comment: `print("\n".join(["".join(map(str,x)) for x in reversed(zip(*field))]))`, `c[::-1]` gives wrong output

Comment: 2 problems: #1 TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence
#2: output is wrong, i need 42334 in first row, not 43324

Comment: @RokDolinar: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: @RokDolinar, `reversed(list(zip(*field))`

Comment: Yeah, the newest version. Working in pycharm 3.4.1

Comment: Working as intended! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Knowing you there probably is; is there a benefit to the `[` `]` brackets in the first one-liner? I'd have thought it would be better to omit them and pass join a generator rather a list (obviously pretty trivial in this example, but wondered more generally)

Comment: @GP89: yes, since `str.join()` has to scan the input *twice* it'll convert an iterator to a list first *anyway*. Using a list comprehension is then faster.

Comment: @GP89: see [list comprehension without \[ \], Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024)

Comment: ahh I thought you'd be right :) thanks- wasn't aware it did two loops!

Answer (score 0):

```
def out(field):
    b=''
    a=[]
    while len(field[0])>0:
        for list in field:
            a.append(list.pop())
        a.append("\n")
    a="".join(str(x) for x in a)
    return a 
x=[[1, 2, 4, 4], [4, 1, 4, 2], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
print out(x)
```